# Cant debug any apps on google chromecast device

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I registered the chromecast in chrome developer account but still i am not able to debug any apps. Chromecast is showing up in the developer console, but the inspect button is not visible. I tried debugging my own styled media receiver app.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Answer (score 0):

You might have to restart your device to ensure it downloads the latests configs for development. Also, it is very easy to get the serial number wrong when you register your device in the Google Cast Developer console, so double check that too.